# how to stop node js server from crashing

Tags: javascript, node.js, webserver

I am new to node js. I was trying to create a simple HTTP server. I followed the famous example and created a 'Hello World!' server as follows.

```
var handleRequest = function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res1.end('Hello, World!\n');
};

require('http').createServer(handleRequest).listen(8080);

console.log('Server started on port 8080');
```

Running this code would start the server properly as expected. But trying to access `http://127.0.0.1:8080` would crash it by throwing an error that `res1` is not defined. I would like to have the server still continue running and gracefully report errors whenever it encounters it.

How do I achieve it? I tried try-catch but that isn't helping me :(

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8114990/435413 (autoreboot javascript) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999373/how-do-i-prevent-node-js-from-crashing-try-catch-doesnt-work (prevent crash)

Comment: Hi Benjamin, I purposefully typed it as res1 to generate error. My question is about how to handle such errors without crashing the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a bunch of comments here. First of all, for your example server to work, handleRequest needs to be defined BEFORE using it.

1- What you actually want, which is preventing the process to exit, can be handled by handling uncaughtException ([documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception)) event:

```
var handleRequest = function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res1.end('Hello, World!\n');
};
var server = require('http').createServer(handleRequest);
process.on('uncaughtException', function(ex) {
    // do something with exception
});
server.listen(8080);
console.log('Server started on port 8080');
```

2- I would recomment to use try{} catch(e) {} on your code, such as:

```
var handleRequest = function(req, res) {
    try {
      res.writeHead(200);
      res1.end('Hello, World!\n');
    } catch(e) {
      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end('Boo');
    }
};
```

3- I guess the example was just an example and not actual code, this is a parsing error that can be prevented. I mention this, since you NEED to NOT have parsing errors on Exception catch handlers.

4- Please note that node `process` is going to be replaced in the future with [domain](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html)

5- I'd rather use a framework like [express](http://expressjs.com/), than doing this stuff.

6- Recommended lecture: [StackOverflow - NodeJS best practice for exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling)

Comment: 1 is wrong, 2 is wrong for asynchronous code, 4 is wrong since process is going to be complemented with domain, and domain also works now

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum 1 why? Explain further + it actually works and prevents the app to crash. 2 author never says he needs to handle parse exceptions on async code. 4 domain is in unstable version and node docs says explicitly "use domain INSTEAD OF process"

Comment: Thanks Tom... ponint 1 worked for me... And I will follow your suggestions. I will consider using express.

Answer (score 1):

I am not targeting your question details but your question's title about preventing Node server from crashing. You can probably use **DOMAIN**, this will probably stop your server from crashing when an uncaughtException is thrown.

```
domain = require('domain'),
d = domain.create();

d.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

for more details go http://shapeshed.com/uncaught-exceptions-in-node/

beside using this method must try-catch your block.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should define `handleRequest` before you use it:

```
require('http').createServer(handleRequest).listen(8080);

function handleRequest(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res1.end('Hello, World!\n');
};
```

Or

```
var handleRequest = function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res1.end('Hello, World!\n');
};

require('http').createServer(handleRequest).listen(8080);
```

---

And you should be sure that `res1` also exists.

Comment: Nope, javascript automatically moves "var" statements to the top of the scope.

Comment: Hi @NULL, Yes... the handleRequest should be above the createServer line. My bad. I copy-pasted it wrongly (updating the question now). Now, coming to res1 error, I know the cause of the error. I was trying to ask about gracefully handling it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes `handleRequest` is defined but is `undefined` . It's like writing: `var a; b(a) a = function(){...}`

Comment: no, @BenjaminGruenbaum is right. function declarations are hoisted (which is different from anon function assignment to a var)

Comment: yeah, this way undefined is passed to a function.