# Global error message using Gulp Notify & Plumber

Tags: javascript, error-handling, build-process, gulp

Is it possible to create a global OnError function that I can pass a title and the error message to?

I'm looking to do something like this for all tasks ran with plumber:

```
onError = function(error) {
      $.notify.onError({
        title:    'Error',
        subtitle: '<%= file.relative %> did not compile!',
        message:  '<%= error.message %>'   
      })(error);
    };
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4214095/348314

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply save the onError function as a variable:

```
var onError = notify.onError({
   title:    'Error',
   subtitle: '<%= file.relative %> did not compile!',
   message:  '<%= error.message %>'   
});
```

And in several different gulp-tasks and plumber-functions:

```
gulp.src('./src/*.ext')
  .pipe(plumber({ errorHandler: onError }))
  .pipe(coffee())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
```

and somewhere else:

```
gulp.src('./src/*.scss')
  .pipe(plumber({ errorHandler: onError }))
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(plumber.stop())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
```