# Gulp: Error Messages and Notifications with Plumber

Tags: gulp, gulp-notify

[In this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782341/global-error-message-using-gulp-notify-plumber), it states you can use Gulp-Plumber and Gulp-Notify to display a message and sound each time there is an error. Gulp-Plumber will ensure that Gulp watch will continue to run.

However, when I try it, I keep on getting this error message, which causes Gulp to stop:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

Here is my code:

```
var gulp            = require('gulp'),
    sass            = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    jshint          = require('gulp-jshint'),
    uglify          = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename          = require('gulp-rename'),
    concat          = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify          = require('gulp-notify'),
    plumber         = require('gulp-plumber'),



  var onError = function(err) {
        notify.onError({
                    title:    "Gulp",
                    subtitle: "Failure!",
                    message:  "Error: <%= error.message %>",
                    sound:    "Beep"
                })(err);

        this.emit('end');
         };


//Scripts Task
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src('frontend/build/js/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('frontend/dist/js'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('frontend/dist/scripts'))
       .pipe(notify({ 
           sound: "Frog"
    }));
});


//Styles Task
gulp.task('styles', function() { 
    return sass('frontend/build/scss/', {style: 'expanded'})
    .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('frontend/dist/css/'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles'))
    .pipe(notify({ // Add gulpif here
           sound: "Pop"
   }));

});
```

The only difference between my code and the example is that I have moved onError as a global function so it can be used in both the scripts and styles task. However, even if I move it back inside the styles function, the same error message occurs.

(the code I have posted is abbreviated, the full code can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/299gpx3s/))

Also, is there a way to hide the notification message on success so I just get the sound? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have figured this out by now, but in your full code the onError function is scoped to your styles task, you are also not piping into plumber anywhere in your scripts task.