# How to prevent nodejs console close

Tags: node.js

Is there any alternative to `PHP error_reporting(0)` in nodejs? I want to prevent app from closing after an error, I tried the `try and catch method`, but it doesn't work.
So, how can I prevent `node.js server` from closing after an error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit:
There is an event for uncaught errors:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);
});
```

See duplicate: [Make node.js not exit on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213351/make-node-js-not-exit-on-error)

You could also use `pm2` to run your script, `pm2` will automatically restart your script on crash.

You need to catch the error.
For example

```
try {
  error();
} catch(err) {
 // do nothing
}
```

There is no other way as far as i know. So you could fix or catch these errors only.

Comment: I don't have to fix errors, it's beacause I have a mysql module and It closes if the user/pass is incorrect, so I want to prevent this

Answer (score 3):

After i review source code of node, I found there is a beautiful method to implement "ctrl+c" existing.

Create file block.js, content is:

```
const readline = require('readline')

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
})

const block = (data) => {
    process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
        console.log('Caught exception: ' + err)
    })
    rl.on('SIGINT', () => {
        console.log(data)
        rl.pause()
    })
}

module.exports = {
    block
}
```

Then require this js file in whatever main js file, and run this:

```
const { block } = require('./block.js')

block('Your exiting message!')

// your other js code after here
// ...
```

The block.js file would catch err and "ctrl+c" SIGINT exit.