# uncaughtException after a Protractor run

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

After upgrading to Protractor 4.0.0 and adjusting the config because of the breaking changes, we finally have our tests launching.

Now, the problem is that after a test run it fails with:

```
[09:52:22] E/launcher - "process.on('uncaughtException'" error, see launcher
[09:52:22] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

How to debug this problem and understand what is causing it?

---

Tried to run Protractor in "troubleshoot" mode:

```
$ protractor config/local.conf.js --troubleshoot
```

but got exactly the same output with no details about the error.

Comment: I'm getting this exact same error, but only with firefox for what it's worth.  
After upgrading to 4.0.0,  I ran protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update and got the latest chrome-driver and the launcher is working fine with chrome.  I am running on a mac.

Comment: try using elementor npm library. It is really helpful for creating protractor tests.

Comment: Even I am getting this error after i upgraded to 4.0.0.

Comment: @alecxe did you raise this in protractor github forum? this seems to be an issue, I am getting this with both chrome & firefox. I did some research, it is a node event uncaught exception error. my understanding of nodejs is limited that is why I am unable to handle it. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213351/make-node-js-not-exit-on-error but not sure how to approach this problem!

Comment: @igniteram1 not yet, trying to gather more information and gain understanding of the problem. I've reinstalled everything from scratch, removed the `protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter` (though I doubt it is relevant). Executed `node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update`. And, it started to work after it. Weird.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [currently being fixed](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3384) and there should be a hot fix out soon. The quick fix (before the hot fix is released) is to change the code in your node_modules or revert to 3.3.0.

Edit `node_modules/protractor/built/launcher.js` replace the `uncaughtException` at line 168 with:

```
    process.on('uncaughtException', function (e) {
    var errorCode = exitCodes_1.ErrorHandler.parseError(e);
    if (errorCode) {
        var protractorError = e;
        exitCodes_1.ProtractorError.log(logger, errorCode, protractorError.message, protractorError.stack);
        process.exit(errorCode);
    }
    else {
        logger.error(e.message);
        logger.error(e.stack);
        process.exit(exitCodes_1.ProtractorError.CODE);
    }
});
```

Comment: I still encounter the issue in 403.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading to protractor 4.0.10 seems to solve it.

There were several fixes from 4.0.0 to 4.0.10 in the launcher. See changelog:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what was happening and what is the best way to debug problems like this, but here is what I've done to fix it:

- removed `node_modules` completely
- executed `npm install` (protractor is listed as `^4.0.0` in `package.json`)
- executed `node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update`

And now it works, it does not throw the `uncaughtException` anymore.

---

I've also removed the `protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter`, but I don't think it is relevant.

Also, we've been using `grunt-protractor-runner` to run Protractor tests from a grunt task and I had to [fork it](https://github.com/alecxe/grunt-protractor-runner) and [update `protractor` dependency to `4.0.0`](https://github.com/alecxe/grunt-protractor-runner/commit/a7916108f42b466cb15c611d32be24bae5f8650c).

Comment: It's a bug, I hope this would clear up things https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3384 ;)

Comment: @igniteram1 oh, great, thanks for sharing, I'll watch that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for modify node_modules/protractor/built/launcher.js works.

There might be a error saying "E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 53.0.2785.0" which just need to update your chrome version

Answer (score 0):

I've been using grunt-protractor-runner 4.0.0.
I was testing specific test files and received this error after I noticed that I accidentally commented out all the files in the specs array in my *protractor.conf.js* file.

```
specs:
[
  //'test1-spec.js',
  //'test2-spec.js'
]
```

Hopefully this silly mistake helps someone.