# Protractor and Cucumber.js: expectations doesn't works as expected using promises with mocha

Tags: angularjs, cucumber, protractor, mocha.js, chai-as-promised

I have been trying to testing my angular app using protractor and cucumber, but when i use mocha for create a expectation when the expectation it's false the error spec doesn't show in the console.

The relevant HTML for the route http://localhost:9000/#/form29/form29'

```
...

<h4 class="title">
  The title
</h4>

...
```

And my step file it is:

//form29_steps.js

```
var chai = require('chai'),
        chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised'),
        assert;

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
expect = chai.expect;

module.exports = function () {

    this.Given(/^I am in the form 29 page$/, function (done) {
      browser.get('http://localhost:9000/#/form29/form29');
      done();
    });

    this.Then(/^should be the title "(.*)"/,function(title, done){
        var el = element(by.css('.title'));

        el.getText().then(function(text){
            //a false expect
            expect(title).to.eq('Aaaaa');
            done();
        });

    });

};
```

when the expect its valid its ok, but when the expect failed there aren't a expect failed error and show the following:

```
[16:14:08] E/launcher - "process.on('uncaughtException'" error, see launcher
[16:14:08] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

When i try the same but not using promised this works well

```
this.Then(/^should be the title "(.*)"/,function(title, done){
    var el = element(by.css('.title'));

    expect(title).to.eq('A');
    done(); 
});
```

I get the error that i wish:

```
Message:
     AssertionError: expected 'Formulario 29' to equal 'A'
         at World.<anonymous> (/protractor/test/e2e/features/step_definitions/form29_steps.js:18:20)
         at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

**Why happen this?**

Comment: The uncaught exception can mean different things, but [I had it recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397965/uncaughtexception-after-a-protractor-run).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[16:14:08] E/launcher - "process.on('uncaughtException'" error, see launcher
[16:14:08] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

The above error can be caused due to various reasons mostly related to promises. But it should throw the correct message. There is already a work around provided here https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3384 to catch the exact error message.

You could change the `launcher.ts` file in your protractor dependency as mentioned in above forum to catch the error in order to debug your issue.