# browser.get returning before the given URL completely loads using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, node.js, asynchronous, protractor, cucumberjs

I'm using Protractor with Cucumber to write some tests but I'm stuck at some point. In step after login, I'm rerouting to another page using browser.get(url) function provided by protractor. But it always returns before the page is completely loaded. I have tried many solutions so far but no luck. I have tried with browser.wait, browser.get(url).then(function(){ // code when it loads}) but Im getting 0 positive results.

Here's my code:

```
  // Steps will be implemented here
  this.Given(/^I am logged in as user \'([^\']*)\'$/, function (user, callback) {
    console.log('USER: ' + user);
    browser.driver.get('https://cit-was70-l06/ipa')
    browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('my_xpath')).sendKeys(user);
    browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('my_xpath')).sendKeys(user);
    browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('my_xpath')).click().then(callback);
  });

  this.Then(/^The screen is shown, with title \'([^\']*)\'$/, function (title, callback) {
    console.log('Title from feature file: ' + title);
    var url = 'some/url/in/application/';
    browser.get(url).then(function(){
      // This portion executes before page is completely loaded.
      // So if I try to get any element, it throws me an error.
      // [15:32:13] E/launcher - "process.on('uncaughtException'" error, see 
      // launcher
      // [15:32:13] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
      // It works if I add static delay to wait for page load completely
      // but that will not be a good solution if I have too much pages to test
      callback();
    });
    console.log('After page laoad');
  });
```

Any suggested work around will be much appreciated.

Comment: Related: [uncaughtException after a Protractor run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397965/uncaughtexception-after-a-protractor-run).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  [15:32:13] E/launcher - "process.on('uncaughtException'" error, see launcher
  [15:32:13] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

The above error can be caused due to various reasons mostly related to promises. But it should throw the correct message. There is already a work around provided here https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3384 to catch the exact error message.

You could change the `launcher.ts` file in your `protractor` dependency as mentioned in above forum to catch the error inorder to debug your issue.

And I would suggest you to `return` your promises instead of `callbacks` when writing step definitions in `protractor-cucumber`, in this way cucumber would know when to complete its async actions.

Comment: There is no lib dir

Comment: it has been fixed and scheduled for next path release , you have to change the `launcher.js` file , here is the detailed work around : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397965/uncaughtexception-after-a-protractor-run

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.check whether it helps.

```
browser.get(url);
browser.waitForAngular();
then try to call your function.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ***protractor.ExpectedConditions*** to check visibility of any elements on page which will be displayed after successful login. Write a customized method as shown below.

If element displayed, then navigate other page using browser.get();

```
Code Snippet

 EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
 //targetElement=element(locator);
 this.isElementVisible = function (targetElement, timeOut) {
   'use strict';
   timeOut = timeOut !== undefined ? timeOut : 8000;
   browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(targetElement), 
      timeOut).thenCatch(function()   
       {
        assert.fail(' element is not visible');
      });
 };
```