# "Process finished with exit code 199" is populating when run the config file

Tags: node.js, eclipse, jasmine, protractor, webstorm

**I Executed the config file, browser invoked after that the below Error is appeared in console.**

Tools Used **Webstrom/Eclipse**
Protractor **Version :4.0.0**

---

"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 2016.2.3\bin\runnerw.exe"

"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"

C:\Users\surya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js

C:\samplepro\conf.js

I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver

E/launcher - "process.on('uncaughtException'" error, see launcher

E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199

Process finished with exit code 199

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uncaughtException after a Protractor run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397965/uncaughtexception-after-a-protractor-run)

Answer (score 3):

Protractor version 4.0.0 have one important bug with uncaughtException [uncaughtException after a Protractor run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397965/uncaughtexception-after-a-protractor-run)

You should use protractor version >4.0.1

After upgrade the protractor version you should be able to see what is the problem

Comment: to update the Protractor  "npm install -g protractor"

Comment: After updating the protractor version - "npm install -g protractor" and Web driver update - "webdriver-manager update" , it's working for me